# Unable to understand the XSLT code

Tags: xslt

I have code something like below in one of my XSLT -

```
<div>
<ul class="toplevel-Video group Video-coll-left">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//VideoNode[@Video='Yes'][1]" />
</ul>
<ul class="toplevel-Video group Video-coll">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//VideoNode[@Video='Yes'][position()>=2 and last()>position()]" />
</ul>
<ul class="toplevel-Video group Video-coll-right">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//VideoNode[@Video='Yes'][last()]" />
</ul>
</div>
```

and unable to understand that what it mean to say [1] in the below code

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//VideoNode[@Video='Yes'][1]" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `//X[1]` and `(//X)[1]`. The first expression selects every X that is the first X child of its parent; the second selects the first X in the document. In effect, the "[]" operator has higher precedence than the "//" operator. More formally, `//X[1]` expands to `root()/(descendant-or-self::node())/(child::X[1])`, while `(//X)[1]` expands to `(root()/descendant-or-self::node()/child::X)[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It just means the first node in the set.  So the first `ul` contains the first elements, the middle `ul` contains all nodes except the first and last, and the last `ul` contains the last node.

Comment: But <ul class="toplevel-Video group Video-coll-right"> <xsl:apply-templates select="//VideoNode[@Video='Yes'][last()]" /> </ul> gives me 3 VideoNode nodes. Ideally it should give only one

Comment: I'm not to sure about that, but I think [Michael Kay's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447668/264676) is relevant to your problem.  Perhaps you're accidentally selecting the wrong nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The `select` expression is an XPATH expression that says:

- starting from root or anything else (`//`)
- find tags names `VideoNode`
- but only those having the attribute `Vidoe` with a value of `Yes`
- return the first such node `[1]`

Now, the `[1]` part selects the first matching node of a parent, so if you have multiple parents for your `VideoNode` nodes, then the result should be multiple such nodes...

e.g.:

```
<root>
    <parent1>
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/> <!-- this gets selected -->
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/>
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/>
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/>
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/>
    </parent1>
    <parent2>
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/> <!-- and so does this! -->
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/>
        <VideoNode Video='Yes'/>
    </parent2>
</root>
```

So the `[1]` is *local*, not global.

Comment: But <ul class="toplevel-Video group Video-coll-right">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//VideoNode[@Video='Yes'][last()]" />
</ul> gives me  3 VideoNode nodes. Ideally it should give only one